# How to save facebook user gallery image from url to directory?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am using this code to save user gallery images on my website.First when user logged in then all gallery images loads and when user will select any image then i need to save that image in a directory. This is my code. Image is saveing with the name but image size is zero.

```
$file = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/[Fb-Photo-ID]/picture?width=378&height=378&access_token=[Access-Token]');     
$img = file_put_contents($target_dir['path'].'/'."facebook3.jpg",$file);
```

This is code of image gallery.

```
<script>
        /**
         * This is the getPhoto library
         */

        function makeFacebookPhotoURL( id, accessToken ) {
            //alert(id);
            return 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/' + id + '/picture?access_token=' + accessToken;
        }

        function login( callback ) {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                    if (callback) {
                        callback(response);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
            },{scope: 'publish_actions,user_location,user_photos,email'} );
        }
        function getAlbums( callback ) {
            FB.api(
                    '/me/albums',
                    {fields: 'id,cover_photo'},
                    function(albumResponse) {
                        console.log( ' got albums ' );
                        if (callback) {
                            callback(albumResponse);
                            console.log(albumResponse);
                        }
                    }
                );

        }

        function getPhotosForAlbumId( albumId, callback ) {
                    //alert(albumId);
                    console.log(albumId);
            FB.api(
                    '/'+albumId+'/photos',
                    {fields: 'id'},
                    function(albumPhotosResponse) {
                        console.log( ' got photos for album ' + albumId );
                        if (callback) {
                            callback( albumId, albumPhotosResponse );

                        }
                    }
                );
        }

        function getLikesForPhotoId( photoId, callback ) {
            FB.api(
                    '/'+albumId+'/photos/'+photoId+'/likes',
                    {},
                    function(photoLikesResponse) {
                    console.log(photoLikesResponse);
                        if (callback) {

                            callback( photoId, photoLikesResponse );
                        }
                    }
                );
        }

        function getPhotos(callback) {

            var allPhotos = [];

            var accessToken = '';

            login(function(loginResponse) {
                    accessToken = loginResponse.authResponse.accessToken || '';
                     //console.log(accessToken);
                    getAlbums(function(albumResponse) {
                            var i, album, deferreds = {}, listOfDeferreds = [];

                            for (i = 0; i < albumResponse.data.length; i++) {
                                album = albumResponse.data[i];

                                deferreds[album.id] = $.Deferred();
                                listOfDeferreds.push( deferreds[album.id] );
                                getPhotosForAlbumId( album.id, function( albumId, albumPhotosResponse ) {
                                        var i, facebookPhoto;
                                        for (i = 0; i < albumPhotosResponse.data.length; i++) {
                                            facebookPhoto = albumPhotosResponse.data[i];
                                            allPhotos.push({
                                                /* 'id' :   facebookPhoto.id,
                                                'added' :   facebookPhoto.created_time, */
                                                'url'   :   makeFacebookPhotoURL( facebookPhoto.id, accessToken )
                                            });
                                        }
                                        deferreds[albumId].resolve();
                                    });
                            }

                            $.when.apply($, listOfDeferreds ).then( function() {
                                if (callback) {
                                    callback( allPhotos );

                                }
                            }, function( error ) {
                                if (callback) {
                                    callback( allPhotos, error );
                                }
                            });
                        });
                });
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        /**
         * This is the bootstrap / app script
         */

        // wait for DOM and facebook auth
        var docReady = $.Deferred();
        var facebookReady = $.Deferred();

        $(document).ready(docReady.resolve);

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId      : '00000000000',
              channelUrl : '//conor.lavos.local/channel.html',
              status     : true,
              cookie     : true, 
              xfbml      : true
            });
            facebookReady.resolve();
        };

        $.when(docReady, facebookReady).then(function() {
            if (typeof getPhotos !== 'undefined') {
                getPhotos( function( photos ) {
                    //console.log(photos);
                    var str= JSON.stringify(photos);

                    var contact=jQuery.parseJSON(str);

                    $.each( photos, function( index, value ){
                        $.each( value, function( index1, value1 ){

                            console.log(value);
                                    //console.log( index1+value1);
                                    //console.log( index1+value1);
                                    //console.log( index1+value1);

                        $("#images").append('<a href="javascript:;" class="myimg"><img height="100" width="150" src='+value1+' /></a>');

 $("a.myimg img").click(function()
                    {
                        var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');

                        $("#fbimg").val(imgSrc);

                    }); 


                                }); 
                                });

                });
            }
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried to identify whether you have something in $file ? And what responded FB to you?

Comment: What's `$target_dir`? do you have write permissions on the dir you want to save the photo ? Do you have the correct `[Fb-Photo-ID]` and `[Access-Token]` ?

Comment: It is not showing anything when i tried to print $file.

Comment: target dir path is directory where i want to save the image and access token and id are also fine because when i hit the url then it is showing image.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using FB API in incorrect way.

1. You should have version of your API request
2. check access_token -> whether it has correct wright ( user_photos )
3. in such way of request you won't receive image content. You can receive only link on static image.
4. So only after receiving of image - you can save it

Your link should be like :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/[photo_Id]/picture?access_token=[access_token_with_wrights]
```

this will return JSON data kind of :

```
{
  "data": {
    "is_silhouette": false,
    "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/[image_url]"
  }
}
```

[read more here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo) and you can add additional params for thumbs ( aka "images" )

---

**UPDATE**

so in your way it would be like :

```
$jsonstring = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/[photo_Id]?fields=picture,images&access_token=[access_token_with_wrights]
"));

$file = file_get_contents($jsonstring['images'][0]['source']) /* chose your size */
$img = file_put_contents($target_dir['path'].'/'."facebook3.jpg",$file);
```

OR use [FB PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php)

---

**UPDATE #2**

If you received static link to image from JS => just use it, not the graphApi request. It means that you can **SEND ALREADY RECEIVED LINKS** to server side. And they should be like **https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/XXXXXX** and after receiving them on server side you can just use them. and make

```
$file = file_get_contents("https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/");
```

But link should not be on http://graph.facebook.com!

---

**UPDATE 3**

Yes, it's correct request ( from question ).
JS code for images with static path:

```
FB.api(
        '/' + albumId + '/photos',
        { fields: 'id,images' }, /* main is images array in response */
        function ( albumPhotosResponse ) {
           console.log( ' got photos for album ' + albumId );
           if ( callback ) {
                    callback( albumId, albumPhotosResponse );
           }
} );
```

parse the path for image from there.

Comment: i have added my javascript code also.I am getting image url with accesstoken and facebook id.

Comment: @php_dev how your JS connected with PHP?

Comment: when all images comes the on click of a image i am saving its value in input type and when user submit the form then with that input type i am getting image url.

Comment: If you have static links to image - you don't need any access_token. check what you are sending on server side. it should be kind of https://scontent-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/XXXXXXXX

Comment: in my javascript i am getting image url in this way.  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/[photo_Id]/picture?access_token=[access_token_with_wrights] . You can check it just copy and paste the code.

Comment: i am not getting the response in this way. https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/XXXXXX .Is there any problem in my javascript code?

Comment: @php_dev Do you show images on JS side? If yes - it means you have static links. If now - just request them using JS SDK . and send it to backend.

Comment: i am using js sdk  to get images. FB.api(
                    '/'+albumId+'/photos',
                    {fields: 'id'},
                    function(albumPhotosResponse) {
                        console.log( ' got photos for album ' + albumId );
                        if (callback) {
                            callback( albumId, albumPhotosResponse );

                        }
                    }
                );
        }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111559/discussion-between-xaqwerx-and-php-dev).